# Postgres - Select all rows with a date column value within a range of another row's value?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use a date value as a starting point to construct a date range within a single postgres query. The date value would be something like

`SELECT upgraded_at FROM accounts ORDER BY upgraded_at DESC limit 1;`

which would then be used as the starting point. I then want to do something like

`SELECT * from accounts WHERE upgraded_at >= (basis_date - 2 days) AND upgraded_at < (basis_date + 2 days);`

Ideally I'd like to accomplish this with a single query. So I'll need to some subquery to get the starting date, then use that as a variable within the rest of the query.

Also eventually I'm going to be doing this within Sequelize. I definitely need the raw SQL way to do it but I'm also curious if later there's a Sequelize-specific way.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually avoid making two references to the basis date here.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MAX(upgraded_at) OVER () AS max_upgraded_at
    FROM accounts
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE upgraded_at - max_upgraded_at BETWEEN -2 AND 2;
```